# Quick edit many SKU fields in Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce

Is there a way to quickly edit many SKU fields in Drupal Commerce? I have the Back Office quick edit and its great for price or stock control, I have also tried editable views but it seems that the SKU field can only be edited by accessing a full edit of the individual product. With 500+ products this could take quite a while. We have a seperate database external to Drupal where the product ids don't correspond to the SKU but would like to make that happen so in the future we could use feeds to import price changes, product title changes etc.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of doing this is as follows:

1. Create a view for the products including SKU & Product Id (assigned by drupal commerce)
2. Export the view into a csv using the views_data_export module.
3. Amend your SKUs in the csv file using any text editor. This should make it easier to amend.
4. Create a feeds importer, with settings "Update existing commerce products", and using the "Product Id" as unique key (instead of SKU).
5. Load the amended csv to update the SKUs in the database.